# Acumatica Report Writer extract date to show other form

Tags: c#, .net, acumatica

[image]

how to changes Start period date and End period date other date form? We want to show 09-2022 to September-2022.
How to solve is this date format?

- Start period : 09-2022
- End period   : 09-2022

This format is false.

We want to

- Start period : September-2022
- End period   : September-2022

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do that will be to add the MasterFinPeriod table to the report and add two relationships to the table which you are filtering by Fin Period. In my case I am filtering the INItemSiteHistByPeriod table, so the relationship is added to it. Then you need to change the formula for your Start and End Periods formulas to be as below and that will result in a report with the month being the text description of the period and the year. Of course, this works with the assumption that your Fin Period descriptions are the default ones which are the Month names.

```
=[StartPeriod.Descr]+'-'+[StartPeriod.FinYear]
=[EndPeriod.Descr]+'-'+[StartPeriod.FinYear]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]